# Kubernetes deployment not auto-terminating after successful run of command

Tags: kubernetes, kinetica

I have a Kubernetes cluster in which I've created a deployment to  run a pod. Unfortunately after running it the pod does not want to self-terminate, instead it enters a continuous state of restart/CrashLoopBackOff cycle.

The command (on the entry point) runs correctly when first deployed, and I want it to run only one time.

I am programatically deploying the docker image with the entrypoint configured, using the Python K8s API. Here is my deployment YAML:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kio
  namespace: kmlflow
  labels:
    app: kio
    name: kio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kio
      name: kio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kio
        name: kio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kio-ingester
        image: MY_IMAGE
        command: ["/opt/bin/kio"]
        args: ["some", "args"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      restart: Never
  backofflimit: 0
```

Thanks for any help

Output from kubectl pod  is:

```
Name:               ingest-160-779874b676-8pgv5
Namespace:          kmlflow
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com/172.30.255.205
Start Time:         Thu, 11 Oct 2018 13:31:20 -0400
Labels:             app=kio
                    name=kio
                    pod-template-hash=3354306232
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.0.228
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/ingest-160-779874b676
Containers:
  kio-ingester:
    Container ID:  docker://b67a682d04e69c2dc5c1be7e02bf2e4cf7a12a7557dfbe642dfb531ca4b03f07
    Image:         kinetica/kinetica-intel
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://docker.io/kinetica/kinetica-intel@sha256:eefbb6595eb71822300ef97d5cbcdac7ec58f2041f8190d3a2ba9cffd6a0d87c
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /opt/gpudb/bin/kio
    Args:
      --source
      kinetica://172.30.50.161:9191::dataset_iris
      --destination
      kinetica://172.30.50.161:9191::iris5000
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Thu, 11 Oct 2018 13:33:27 -0400
      Finished:     Thu, 11 Oct 2018 13:33:32 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-69wkn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-69wkn:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-69wkn
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                                    Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled  2m39s                default-scheduler                       Successfully assigned kmlflow/ingest-160-779874b676-8pgv5 to 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com
  Normal   Created    89s (x4 over 2m28s)  kubelet, 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com  Created container
  Normal   Started    89s (x4 over 2m28s)  kubelet, 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com  Started container
  Warning  BackOff    44s (x7 over 2m15s)  kubelet, 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling    33s (x5 over 2m28s)  kubelet, 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com  pulling image "kinetica/kinetica-intel"
  Normal   Pulled     33s (x5 over 2m28s)  kubelet, 02-w540-02.glebe.kinetica.com  Successfully pulled image "kinetica/kinetica-intel"
```

There is no output from `Kubectl logs <crashing-pod>` because a successful run of the command KIO with the injected parameters does not print anything to standard output.

Comment: It's basically crashing or exiting unsuccessfully. Can you post the output of `kubectl describe <pod-that-is-crashing>` and also `kubectl logs <pod-that-is-crashing>`

Comment: Original post updated with this information. Is it possible that the command (which is an application run from within the pod) is not exiting with a code 0 as it should because it works correctly on the first iteration before it restarts and proceeds to the crash loop. Running ``kubectl get pods`` during the process shows that the pod status does move from "ContainerCreating" to "Running" to "Completed" at which point I can see that it has done what it was supposed to do. But then after a few seconds the pod status starts cycling from "Running" to "Completed" to "CrashLoopBackOff"

Comment: Is it possible this should be launched as a job using the batch/v1 API instead of a deployment using apps/v1?

Comment: Yeah, posted an answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to run your task one time and finish after a successful completion you should consider using [Kubernetes Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) or [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/)

Something like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: kio
  namespace: kmlflow
  labels:
    app: kio
    name: kio
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kio
        name: kio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kio-ingester
        image: MY_IMAGE
        command: ["/opt/bin/kio"]
        args: ["some", "args"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      restart: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

To delete the jobs automatically if you have Kubernetes 1.12 or later you can use [`ttlSecondsAfterFinished`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically). Unfortunately, you if you are using Kuberbetes 1.11 or earlier you will have to delete them manually or you can set up a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to do it.

Comment: This solution works well, thank you. I wonder if there is a way for jobs to automatically delete themselves once their SUCCESSFUL status reaches 1?

Comment: Yes. You can use `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` if you are using k8s 1.12 or later. If you are using k8s 1.11 or earlier you will have to delete them manually or build your own automation. Updated the answer.